How to find generators list to find all subgroups?
In the video from Professor Macauley
Visual Group Theory, Lecture 3.4: Direct products
There is an exercice at 13 min :45 sec : find all the subgroups of Z2xZ2xZ2 (he says : it's a very easy easy exercice !)
I did not find an easy way to find all the subgroup, so I just did it with the brute force:
https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=odboca
which gives me :
1  subgroups of Z2xZ2xZ2  with 1 elements in each subgroup
[[(0, 0, 0)]]
7  subgroups of Z2xZ2xZ2  with 2 elements in each subgroup
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)]
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
7  subgroups of Z2xZ2xZ2  with 4 elements in each subgroup
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)]
1  subgroups of Z2xZ2xZ2  with 8 elements in each subgroup
[[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]]

In the comments @smackronme gives the generators list:
a,b,c,ab,bc,ca,abc (these are cyclic) <b,c> , <a,b> ,<a,c>,<c,ab>,<b,ac>,<a,bc>,,<bc,ac,ab> (non-cyclic) other two are identity and z2z2z2
How did he find this generator list  to produce all the subgroups ?
and is the correspondence I did below with subgroup element to @smackronme generators list is ok ?
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)] a
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)] b
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1)] ab
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)] c
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1)] ac
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)] ab
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)] abc
7  subgroups of Z2xZ2xZ2  with 4 elements in each subgroup
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)] a,b,ab
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1)] a,c,ac
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)] a,ab,abc
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)] b,c,ab
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)] b,ab,abc
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)] ab,a,abc
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)] bc,ac,ab

On the other hand I thought I understood that the generators of a group were actions which when applied to the elements of a set generated this group,here he call generators elements of the group, I'm confused.

Generators are elements of the group that generates the group through various combinations of the generators, their powers, and their inverses. So they are elements of the group.

Ok, thank you @CyclotomicField
